# Можно ли передать this через параметр шаблона?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Компилятор VS2017.

Есть такой код, который работает:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class a {

    int aint;
    T* tptr;

public:

    a(T* ptr1) :tptr(ptr1) {}

};

class b:public a<b> {

    int bint;

public:

    b() :a(this) {}
    void print() { cout <<endl<<"run class b"; }

};



int main()
{
    cout << endl<<"Hello World!";

    b bb;
    bb.print();
}
```

Теперь хочу сделать так, чтобы передавать указатель this от класса "b" не через конструктор класса "a", а через параметр шаблона. Пишу что-то вроде:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class b;

template <class T* ttptr> class a {

    int aint;
    T* tptr;

public:

    a() :tptr(ttptr){}

};

class b :public a <this> {

    int bint;

public:

    b() {}
    void print() { cout <<endl<<"run class b"; }

};

int main()
{
    cout << endl<<"Hello World!";

    b bb;
    bb.print();
}
```

Но компилятор ругается на строку:

```
class b :public a <this>
```

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли передать указатель this через параметр шаблона?
2. Если можно, то как это сделать?
3. Если нельзя, то почему?

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY. В качестве параметра шаблона должно использоваться константное выражение, а вы пытаетесь использовать неопределенный указатель на экземпляр класса, который еще даже не определили. Если написать два экземпляра `b b1{}; b b2{};` то от чего по-вашему должен будет наследоваться каждый из них? В приведенном коде нет никаких причин для использования шаблона и вообще базового класса.

Comment: @VTT Конечно, это упрощенный пример. Реальный пример кода слишком велик, чтобы его приводить здесь. И в реальном примере есть причины и для использования шаблона, и для использования базового класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` никогда не считается константой времени компиляции, так что нельзя. Не представляю, как это вообще могло бы работать.

К тому же, `this` не существует снаружи нестатических функций.

---

Можно сделать намного проще. Внутри `a<T>` можно даункастить `this` в `T *` через `static_cast<T *>(this)`, так что никакой указатель в полях класса хранить не нужно.

Comment: В классе "a" нужен именно указатель на экземпляр производного класса. Можно, конечно, его получить с помощью RTTI, но это не честно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 А почему нужен? И `static_cast` не использует RTTI.

Comment: С помощью static_cast нельзя получить указатель на производный класс из указателя на базовый класс. Можно только наоборот, получить указатель на базовый класс из указателя на производный класс.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Нет, можно в обе стороны. Кроме отдельных случаев (например когда базовый класс - виртуальный; либо когда от базового класса наследуешься несколько раз - тогда нужна цепочка `static_cast`ов). Естественно, в отличие от `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast` не выдает никаких ошибок во время выполнения, так что нужно кастовать аккуратно.

Comment: Нет, static_cast только для преобразования указателей вниз по иерархии типов без проверки типа. Для преобразования указателей вверх по иерархии типов static_cast не работает.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Пруф: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b517b85eb8cc93b3

Comment: Мой мир рухнул.